# CSS - General explanation

Tags: html, css

I've never actually learned HTML or CSS properly, all of my knowledge comes from internet surfing and generally playing about with it. So i wanted to finally get some thing cleared up.

Firstly in my current 'messing about', i have a main div but that div will not sit at the very top of the page! It's at least 5 pixels from the top. I don't get it! I solved it once but i can't remember. There is an image of what i mean here: http://puu.sh/6jQUF.jpg

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="Main">
    This is a test.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#Main {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width: 900px;
height: 1200px;
outline: black solid thin;
padding: 20px;
top: 0px;
}
```

I'm sure it just something simple, i apologies for that.

Now another thing i have never understood is that in CSS can two divs sit beside each other, ie one has the float left property and the other float right thus pushing against each other and sitting beside each other, whenever i try this they end up ignoring the fact they are running into each other and both go to the left and right sides of the page. 
I really hope i don't sound like an idiot I'm sure this is possible.

Lastly on the topic
If i have a main container how can i divs to stay in that container? I have tried this just by placing the div within in the container but that doesn't work.
Somebody please explain this, I would really appreciate that.
Thanks

Comment: One question per question, please.

Answer (score 0):

The body has a default margin. Clear it with:

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6dg9j/)**

If you want two divs to sit next to each other, either float them both left or both right, or make then inline, or inline-block elements.

I can't answer your question of "Lastly on the topic If i have a main container how can i divs to stay in that container? I have tried this just by placing the div within in the container but that doesn't work." as it makes no sense without code.

Answer (score 0):

This happen because for default all elements has properties. In this case the tag `body` has some margin.

To avoid this kind of issues you can use a general Reset for this properties like this one [Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or the most basic reset:

```
* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border:0;
}
```

Here the * helps to found all the elements on the DOM and set those properties to 0.

Try to keep one question per post. For your second issue I recommend to investigate the property `display:inline-block` and **[This Link to Clarify Floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)**